# 17.10: Drag-and-drop from folders to desktop always copies files

Tags: 17.10, wayland, drag-and-drop

since my upgrade to Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 all files moved with drag-and-drop from any folder to my desktop are copied but not moved.

Using strg+x and strg+v works. When i open the desktop as a folder usual drag-and-drop from different folders do work without copying the files.

Is this a news feature, should i file a bugreport and is there a way to change this? It's a probleme because now i often double files unnoticed.

Edit: this is wayland related. Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 with Xorg performs like before and allows normal drag-and-drop from folders to the desktop.

Edit 2: I filed a bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wayland/+bug/1729887

Comment: Wayland-only issue? Doesn't happen in an Xorg session?

Comment: Exacly. Tested it now, 17.10 with Xorg allows the usual drag-and-drop from folders to the desktop (without copying the files). Should i file a bug report?

Comment: Probably that's a good idea.