# drag'n drop from desktop --> mouse stuck in hand icon

Tags: nautilus, mouse, 17.10, drag-and-drop

This maybe related to [17.10: Drag-and-drop from folders to desktop always copies files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972533/) : When I try to drag a file from the desktop to an open Nautilus window the cursor changes to the copy-cursor (a hand with "+") but nothing else happens. The cursor gets stuck like this when I am over the desktop. In Nautilus the cursor changes back to the normal cursor. Many apps like Firefox and Sublime text are not fully functional anymore, e.g., no rightclick nor mark text with the mouse is possible; in Firefox the cursor stays in the copy-icon mode. I have to log out and log in again to get my system functional again.

But: When I stay on the desktop everything is working normally: e.g., when I drag a file to a folder (or, e.g., the trash icon) on the desktop it moves into that folder. When I open that folder with Nautilus and drag the file to another Nautilus window it also works as expected.

I have a clean install of 17.10 with Wayland.

Can anyone point me to the right direction to track this down? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's nice to have so many help in spelling and expressing my problem... But am I the only one with this? Yesterday I did a clean install onto another machine and have the same problem: As soon as I drag a file from my desktop over a nautilus window the curser changes and wont go back until I log out and back in again.

Comment: I have same problem. I think you should report a bug https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I'm having the same issue, for the second time now since installing 17.10. I love it, otherwise.